Prisma date filtering lagging
I'm using Prisma (v5) for Postgresql, can't say I love it but that's beside the point. I have a model, an abbreviated version is as follows:
model Opportunity {
  id         Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  start_date DateTime?
  end_date   DateTime?

A user interaction triggers an update of the end date to be at the time the user triggers as follows:
await prisma.opportunity.update({
  where: {
    id,
  },
  data: {
    end_date: new Date(),
  }
})

The page the user is on is revalidated (using Nextjs, but I have tried with caching turned off and the same result) and the main query for the page reruns, with filtering on the date as follows:
{
  OR: [
    { end_date: { gte: new Date() } },
    { end_date: null },
  ],
}

I have verified the update to the date works as expected in the DB and showing the timestamp as I would expect. When I run the main query though it still returns the item that had the end_date added. If I wait a couple of minutes, then it works as expected, almost as if there is a lag before the date is considered less than.
As I am using NextJS, the first issue I suspected was a caching issue, but the problem still is evident with caching turned off.
I tried going from gte to gt with no change.
I also have a query for the inverse (i.e. lt: new Date()) to show ended items and that shows the same lag, which at least means it's consistent. Problem is that this makes the system feel so slow and unresponsive.
